# How can I delete only some of the node properties using Cypher?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a node that has a lot of properties. I no longer need many of them. How can I delete the ones that I no longer need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `REMOVE` clause can be used to remove labels and properties both from nodes and relationships. Here is a simple query that does that:

```
MATCH (n:WrongLabel) REMOVE n:WrongLabel, n.property;
```